# Logitech C615 webcam not detected (Mac OS X 10.8.2)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, webcam

I have a Mid-2010 Macbook Pro running Mountain Lion (10.8.2) and I purchased a Logitech C615 webcam because I read it is compatible with Mac. I installed the Logitech Camera Software, opened it and the camera worked for that first session, but when I opened the Logitech software later it immediately crashed and output a diagnostics log. I've tried uninstalling the Logitech software, restarting and re-plugging in the USB with no luck. I've tried plugging the camera's USB cable into my D-link USB hub as well as straight into the Macbook Pro itself. The camera goes undetected in all cases.

Any idea as to how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: try the logitech HD C910 it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing the [macam](http://freecode.com/projects/macam) driver, which works but is not very stable.

> Macam is a user space USB Webcam driver, supporting Aiptek, 3com, Phillips, Creative, Dexxa, DigitalDream, Dolphin Peripherals, IDT, Intel, Kensington, Lifeview, Logitech, and many other Webcams.

Comment: Could you possibly link to the driver software download page, so future visitors can install this?

Answer (score 0):

Driver for this webcam is to be downloaded from [Logitech Website](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/hd-webcam-c615?section=downloads&bit=&osid=9)